# App tab that lets users click to promote your app through facebook, twitter etc

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, facebook

Is there any public code for integrating a "social" tab in your app so that people can share with Facebook, twitter, send to a friend etc?  I have seen this in other apps and its a great idea to let your app users promote the app through their own social networks.

I could code this but if something already exists then great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are talking about [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com)

Its an easy to use library. Will take 30 minutes to configure that.